# Programmatically add a TabItem for a new CollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbaritem

I'm an XCode newbie and I'm trying to achieve what follows with an iOS8 app:

1. create a Tabbed Application
2. with a single initial tab that contains a text field and a button to:

   3. create a new CollectionView
   4. and add a new tab item to reach it
3. be able to repeat the creation n times

Steps 1 and 2 are pretty easy. I'm stucked @ point 3. Now in my project I have:

- MyCollectionViewController which is a default UICollectionViewController where I've changed numberOfSectionsInCollectionView to return 1 section and numberOfItemsInSection to get 3 cells (the reuseIdentifier is set to "MyCell")
- FirstViewController.swift with:

  - an IBOutlet to a UITextField (newTabItemName) to get the title to use for the new TabItem
  - the following IBAction for the UIButton:

    ```
    @IBAction func generateNewTabItem(sender: UIButton) {
        let vc: MyCollectionViewController = MyCollectionViewController()
        vc.title = newTabItemName.text
        self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?.append(vc)
    }
    ```

If I run the app I see the initial view with the text field and the button; if I change the text and click the button I get the TabItem. I can also do that n times as I wanted. The problem is that if I click one of the new tabs I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

I think I'm not that far from what I need but I don't know what's missing.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Bye...

Answer (score 0):

As the error is stating, you cannot initialise a `UICollectionView` without a layout.

See the documentation for [`initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/initWithFrame:collectionViewLayout:), highlighted by myself:

> The layout object to use for organizing items. The collection view
>   stores a strong reference to the specified object. **Must not be nil**.

`UIKit` does provide a default collection view layout in the form of [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewFlowLayout). If you want to do anything more complex you will have to create a custom subclass of [`UICollectionViewLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UICollectionViewLayout).

Wherever you are creating the `UICollectionView` (presumably within `MyCollectionViewController`) would need to be updated to specify such a layout.

Comment: Thanks for you answer; can you help me with some piece of code to do that?

Comment: I'm still looking into it; any additional suggestion is more than welcome.